# how can i install django shop in my system, facing error like ' no module called setuptools '

Tags: django

I am trying to use django shop
but  it  showing me  "no module setuptool"  while im  about  to  install  django  shop through  command  prompt
will  plz guide  someone ...!

This is my  error :

```
C:\django-shop>python setup.py install
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "setup.py", line 1, in <module>
from setuptools import setup, find_packages
ImportError: No module named setuptools
```

Answer (score 1):

I think the answer to your question could , you don't have setuptools installed?

I think setuptools is an extension for the python library

You can install it using this link

https://pypi.python.org/pypi/setuptools

Comment: is it  require admin permissin  to  do this bcz im  facing  same error after installation of setuptools

Comment: i think so . Run as administrator in cmd.

Answer (score 0):

I'd recommend using [virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) to keep things clean and simple.

Once you've got that running, installin django-shop should just be the case of:

```
pip install django-shop
```

Check also requirements files for pip.

Comment: C:\django-shop>pip install django-shop
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.      im facing  this while im trying  with  that  commamd .. what  all  have  to  be install  more  for pip  plz guide  ..!

Comment: install first the pip so that you can use it. With pip it easy for you to install any app

Comment: its asking  me setuptools again  while im  doing through  comand prompt     ...(pip  installation )!

Comment: Have you installed virtual-env first? You'll need to do that, then activate the environment. Virtualenv will install pip in the environment for you. See the virtualenv doc for the different ways of installing it (sorry I'm not very familiar with Windows!)

Comment: yes just now installed virtual-env. and  trying to  install pip with command " easy_install pip ".. ! but confused about the path ,from  where i have to  do this command

Comment: Do not install pip, it's already been installed for you by virtualenv. Where you run the command doesn't matter, you just need to activate the environment first: \path\to\env\Scripts\activate . Then you should be able to use pip.

Comment: Just saw Windows 7 is a bit restrictive, check the notes on that if you're using it: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv

Answer (score 0):

Every time you installed an app try to search for their documentation, it will answer your problem.

Documentation for django-shop:

https://django-shop.readthedocs.org/en/latest/tutorial.html